# To select optionbutton from the frames in VB

Tags: vb6

I've used 4 optionbuttons in each frame on the from. Like wise i've taken 10 frames on the form.. now i just want to store the value of those optionbuttons from each frame in the MSaccess database.. So the result in the database will be 10 values of optionbuttons for each frame.. Please Help me out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is actually "How can I get the selected option button in a group", then you need to check each in turn.
The very simplest is:

```
'Get the selected option from frame 1
If Frame1Option1.Value Then
  Value1 = 1
ElseIf Frame1Option2.Value Then
  Value1 = 2
ElseIf Frame1Option3.Value Then
  Value1 = 3
ElseIf Frame1Option4.Value Then
  Value1 = 4
End If

'Get the selected option from frame 2
If Frame2Option1.Value Then
  Value2 = 1
ElseIf Frame2Option2.Value Then
  Value2 = 2
ElseIf Frame2Option3.Value Then
  Value2 = 3
ElseIf Frame2Option4.Value Then
  Value2 = 4
End If
```

If you make them a control array in each frame, then you can simplify the code to something like:

```
Dim Index As Long

'Get the selected option from frame 1
For Index = Frame1Options.LBound To Frame1Options.UBound
  If Frame1Options(Index).Value Then Value1 = Index
Next
```

Setting them then becomes just as simple:

```
Frame1Options(Value1).Value = True
```